# python read file enconding difference between linux and windows

Tags: linux, windows, python-2.7

I would like to know whether there is a difference in how files are being opened and read between linux and windows, e.g:

```
data_file = open(fileName, 'r').read()
pkey_file = open('private.pem', 'r').read()
```

Will there be a differences in the data of data_file and pkey_file between windows and linux?

Thanks,
K.

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference in EOF :

Windows \r\n

Linux \n

there is other caracters..

use commande line `dos2unix`

Comment: dos2unix isn't available everywhere easily ; I just popped something that should be a no-brainer to get to work everywhere, and the command line is a bit simpler : https://github.com/mdolidon/endlines :)

Comment: why don't you try the 2 modes - r and rb? That should solve the issue